# Creating partition using parted instead of fdisk

Tags: parted

I have a script which uses the following command to add a partition to /dev/sda

```
cat <<-EOF |fdisk /dev/sda                                                                                           
    n                                                                                                             


    w                                                                                                             
    EOF
```

I want to use parted instead of fdisk (fdisk is not compatible with my Linux).
Can i use simply parted instead of fdisk in the above script or how can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same script logic for parted, but parted has to be invoked via `parted -s` (don't run interactively). Wheter you can use the exact same commands in your HEREDOC is unknown to me as I don't use parted. Try a manual dry run, note the commands, and put them in the HEREDOC part of your script.

Comment: another question. How can i create a partition using all the free space in parted. is there a begin end option like parted -s /dev/sda logical begin end?

Comment: I mean without fixing the size, just assigning all the available free space to the new partition?

Comment: @Coffe_Mug you probably want to start with `info parted`...

Comment: @derobert I could not find anything other than specifying the start and end in numbers! For example fdisk can determine the start of the next partition automatically and I am wondering if there is a way to do it in parted as well.

Comment: @Coffe_Mug "Running Parted" in that manual says you can use negative numbers to count from end, with "-1s" being the end. Haven't tried it myself...